# Slow attribute enumeration inside NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring, enumeration

I'm building an app which relies on string attributes to display different sorts of data while editing a text. Certain attributes are then rendered differently, basically on every keypress, but only in the line range.

This operation is done using a simple enumeration block with a line object, which knows its own range inside the attributed string.

```objectivec
- (void)formatLine:(Line*)line {
    // Line knows its range inside the text view / attributed string
    [textView.textStorage enumerateAttributesInRange:line.textRange
             options:0
             usingBlock:^(NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey,id> * _Nonnull attrs, 
             NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                  // Set background etc.
    }];
}
```

However, it turns out that enumerating an attributed range is very, very slow, especially if the `NSMutableAttributedString` is pretty long, even if the enumerated ranges themselves are usually only 100-300 characters in length. Setting the visual attributes (such as background/foreground color) don't do much difference, the bottleneck is enumeration itself – or maybe requesting a range for enumeration?

Is there a smarter way to retrieve ranges for attributes, or should I just scrap my current logic and start over?

Comment: Show just one of the etc. How do you e.g. set the backgroud?

Comment: How about storing the ranges with attributes in a separate array?

Comment: Setting attributes (background/foreground colors etc.) don't actually do much difference. The bottleneck is the enumeration itself. I'd be glad to save the ranges into a separate array, but it would require a lot of double-checking when editing the document, so that all changes would be correct in two different datasets. I'd rather use the attributed string, if in any way possible.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'll provide a sample project ASAP. It's not really an issue but a Cocoa problem, I guess. Wanted to check if somebody has a clear idea on how to iterate the string more efficiently.

Comment: It depends on the string and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Maybe you do not need to iterate through the whole string. Maybe you can quickly locate the chunk where you want to make changes and then just change there rather than the way you do now?

Comment: @skaak That's pretty much what I'm doing. The bottleneck seems to be requesting this range for enumeration inside the `NSAttributedString`. It doesn't actually matter how long or short the range itself is. I'll try to provide a simplified project to demonstrate the issue, it just requires some modification to existing, elaborate classes.

Comment: "The bottleneck seems to be requesting this range for enumeration" – it is possible to see why that might be the issue. Could you reasonably/easily keep your text as a collection of lines rather than a single string you index into to get the lines? That could work if your attribute ranges don't span your lines and should speed up the attribute enumeration.